# UserPicker input element like GMAIL

Tags: jquery, user-interface, input, gmail, label

I'm searching an userpicker that looks like Gmail, that when you add a "To" address, it becomes a label, or like StackOverflow when you add tags

I've found this plugin:
 http://htmlpreview.github.com/?https://github.com/ErikNoren/entitypicker/blob/master/entitypickerdemo.html 
but I would like to find more plugins to compare...

In my case, In my case, I need to convert two values (mail and phone) in one label...How can I do it??

Thank you very much!

Comment: You could try adding an enhancement request to the GitHub project. I hear the author is a really nice guy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My current autocomplete plugin of choice is Select2.

You can find it here
http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: Hi! it's so good! But can you change the tag value by click over?

Comment: clickover? I dont know what you mean?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for mi english...I mean that if you click over the tag, you can edit its value...as you can do with "to" adresses in gmail

Comment: I see. I don't think it does that out of the box.

Comment: @GeoffAppleford, any luck finding tag input, on which when click, that will be editable... Please share, thanks.

Comment: @UmairSaleem - Sorry, I don't need that functionality so I haven't looked into that at all.

Answer (score 5):

I have created a fiddle using typeahead.js and jquery. Please have a look. 
https://jsfiddle.net/Rohith_KP/k73msa47/

```
! function(source) {
  function extractor(query) {
    var result = /([^,]+)$/.exec(query);
    if (result && result[1])
      return result[1].trim();
    return '';
  }

  function tagTmpl(item) {
    return '<div class="selected">' +
      '<span class="value-wrapper">' +
      '<div class="value">' + item + '</div>' +
      '<div class="value-close"></div>' +
      '</span>' +
      '</div>'
  }
  <!--init  -->
  var initData = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas"],
    tagTmpls = '';
  $.each(initData, function(index, item) {
    tagTmpls += tagTmpl(item);
  })
  $('.multiselect').before(tagTmpls);
  $('.multiselect-display').text(initData.join(', '));
  $('.multiselect').data({
    "selectedValues": initData
  });
  <!-- end init -->
  $('.multiselect').typeahead({
    source: source,
    updater: function(item) {
      var tmpl = tagTmpl(item);
      this.$element.before(tmpl);
      var dataToSend = this.$element.data("selectedValues");
      dataToSend = dataToSend ? dataToSend : [];
      dataToSend.push(item);
      this.$element.data({
        "selectedValues": dataToSend
      })
      return '';
    },
    matcher: function(item) {
      var tquery = extractor(this.query);
      if (!tquery) return false;
      return ~item.toLowerCase().indexOf(tquery)
    },
    highlighter: function(item) {
      var query = extractor(this.query).replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&')
      return item.replace(new RegExp('(' + query + ')', 'ig'), function($1, match) {
        return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>'
      })
    }
  });

  $('.multiselect-wrapper').off('click').on('click', '.value-close', function() {
    $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.siblings('.value').text();
    var selectedValues = $(event.currentTarget).find('.multiselect').data("selectedValues");
    removeStringFromArray(selectedValues, text);
    $this.parents('.selected').hide();
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $this.parents('.selected').remove();
    }, 0)
  })
  $('.multiselect-wrapper').off('click', multislctWrprClickHndlr).on('click', multislctWrprClickHndlr)

  function multislctWrprClickHndlr(e) {
    $("body").off('click', bodyClickHandler).on('click', bodyClickHandler);
    if (!$(e.target).is('.selected')) {
      $('.multiselect').focus()
    }
  };
  $('.multiselect-display').off('click', multislctDsplyClickHndlr).on('click', multislctDsplyClickHndlr)

  function multislctDsplyClickHndlr() {
    $(this).hide()
    $('.multiselect-wrapper').trigger('click').show();
  };

  function bodyClickHandler(e) {
    debugger;
    if ($(e.target).is('.multiselect-wrapper') || $(e.target).parents('.multiselect-wrapper').length || $(e.target).is('.multiselect-display') || $(e.target).parents('.multiselect-display').length) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
    $("body").off('click', bodyClickHandler);
    $('.multiselect-wrapper').hide();
    $('.multiselect-display').text($('.multiselect').data("selectedValues").join(', ')).show()
  }

  function removeStringFromArray(array, search_term) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (array[i] === search_term) {
        array.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}(["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut"]);
```

Comment: Excellent work. But when I'm typing something else other than suggestion,  and then again selecting suggested text from the dropdown, the typing texts disappear. I want to keep the text whatever a user types. What I would love to see is your example + type non-suggestion text. The non-suggestion texts will not have styling or cross button, just simple text.

Comment: @saju thank you. I didn't get the whole picture. I believe you want to add new texts other than autocomplete? right? But why no styling?

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is, a person will start writing, when he want a suggestion he will type @ or ':" sign, the suggestion will appear and he will select one, the selected text will stay normally along with other  text, without @ or ":' sign. That's why no styling. The data source would be from Web Api.

Answer (score 4):

I found this plugin to meet the requirement. Enjoy.

[UserPicker input element like GMAIL](http://tagedit.webwork-albrecht.de/)

Answer (score 2):

Things have gotten easier with plugins Nowadays.

Checkout the https://github.com/jshjohnson/Choices

The plugin works with `text input`, `select` and `multiple select`

With this JS plugin, you can even validate items before you add to a list.

```
For example:

 1. You can write your own validation rules
 2. You can use Regex among other awesome things
```

Its quite easier to initialize:

```
var choice = new Choices(document.getElementById('itemID'), {
  option1:option, 
  option2: option
}
```

It even has several callBacks like; `removingItems`, `addingItems` etc

Example Implementation:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.
A jQuery plugin designed for Email related apps that allow the visitor to add/remove multiple comma-separated email addresses in a single text field. With a basic Email address validation functionality using regular expressions.

https://github.com/pierresh/multiple-emails.js